# Measuring flight/dwell time Python

Tags: python

I have a python code which ideally should measure flight and dwell time when typing a word or characters. In my case, I type: .zoroBen1.

- Dwell time (the duration of time a key is pressed) and
- Flight time (the duration of time between "key up" and the next "key down")

code:

```
def captureKey():

    global c, flight_elapsed, Td, inputstr, dwell_elapsed, index, Tf

    while '\n' not in inputstr:

        c = getch();
        print "Character: " , c

        # This list stores the fight time
        flight_elapsed.append(time.time() - Td)

        inputstr += c
        Tf = time.time()
        index += 1

        # Due to the way the program is written, the first value of the dwell
        # list and flight list are not useful
        del(dwell_elapsed[0])
        del(flight_elapsed[0])

def getch(inp=sys.stdin):

    global flight_elapsed, Td, inputstr, dwell_elapsed, index, Tf

    old = termios.tcgetattr(inp)
    new = old[:]
    new[-1] = old[-1][:]
    new[3] &= ~(termios.ECHO | termios.ICANON)
    new[-1][termios.VMIN] = 1
    try:
        termios.tcsetattr(inp, termios.TCSANOW, new)

        Td = time.time()

        dwell_elapsed.append(time.time() - Tf)
        return inp.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(inp, termios.TCSANOW, old)
```

When I run the program, the contents of flight_elapsed array are in the order of 0.1 (values like 0.52, 0.11, etc.) but the values of dwell_elapsed array are in the order of 10^(-5) (values like 1.2 * 10^(-5), etc.)

Am I calculating the flight/dwell time correctly? Or is there a mistake because I'm not sure if the dwell time is supposed to be this low.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "flight" and "dwell?" What makes you think there is an error here? This looks like something that's probably answerable without domain-specific knowledge, but we need to define some terms for the layman (me!)

Comment: `Flight time` = The time between two key presses on the keyboard. `Dwell time` = The time a key is pressed down on the keyboard. I referred to this website for a data set to compare my code: `http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~keystroke/` That webpage has an excel sheet which has dwell/flight times. They have dwell time order = flight time order = 0.1 which has left me a bit confused. I don't see any references to them having changed the dwell time measurement unit. Maybe I'm looking at it in `seconds` but they're looking at it as `microseconds` but I don't see any reference to it.